# VB.NET - TextChanged automática

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Fala, galera!
Estou tentando realizar data automática. Por exemplo, se eu escolher o ano do campo "Até", no caso ano 2018. O campo "De" calcula automaticamente para ano 2013.

Conforme print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui automatizar apenas esse. Mas quando eu quiser alterar o campo "Até", de 18/04/2018 para 18/04/2015. O campo "De" permanece o ano 2013.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero é calcular cinco anos diferença.

Segue o meu código:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class FormRelatorio
    Dim XcelApp As New Excel.Application()

    'Private Sub carregaGrid()
    '    Try
    '        Dim dt As New DataTable
    '        dt.Columns.Add("Codigo", GetType(Integer))
    '        dt.Columns.Add("Nome", GetType(String))
    '        dt.Columns.Add("Admissao", GetType(DateTime))
    '        dt.Columns.Add("Setor", GetType(Integer))
    '        dt.Columns.Add("Salario", GetType(Double))
    '        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    '        dr("Codigo") = 1
    '        dr("Nome") = "João Torres"
    '        dr("Admissao") = DateTime.Now
    '        dr("Setor") = 20
    '        dr("Salario") = 20000
    '        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    '        dr = dt.NewRow()
    '        dr("Codigo") = 2
    '        dr("Nome") = "Jennifer"
    '        dr("Admissao") = DateTime.Now
    '        dr("Setor") = 40
    '        dr("Salario") = 20000
    '        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    '        dgvDados.DataSource = dt
    '    Catch ex As Exception
    '        MessageBox.Show("Erro" + ex.Message)
    '    End Try
    'End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub gerarBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles gerarBtn.Click
        If dgvDados.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Try
                XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)

                For i As Integer = 1 To dgvDados.Columns.Count
                    XcelApp.Cells(1, i) = dgvDados.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
                Next
                '
                For i As Integer = 0 To dgvDados.Rows.Count - 2
                    For j As Integer = 0 To dgvDados.Columns.Count - 1
                        XcelApp.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvDados.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                    Next
                Next
                '
                XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit()
                '
                XcelApp.Visible = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message)
                XcelApp.Quit()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Relatorio_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'AntaqDataSet.T400_ATRACACAO' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Dim dbase As New dBase
        Me.T400_ATRACACAOTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AntaqDataSet.T400_ATRACACAO)
        ' carregaGrid()
        dgvDados.DataSource = dbase.GetAllAtracacao()
        Dim dtEscolha As DateTime
        dtEscolha = dtpAtual.Text
        txtBoxDe.Text = dtEscolha.AddYears(-5)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MaskedTextBox2_MaskInputRejected(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MaskInputRejectedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvDados_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDados.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Private Sub dtpAtual_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpAtual.ValueChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtBoxDe_MaskInputRejected(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MaskInputRejectedEventArgs) Handles txtBoxDe.MaskInputRejected
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(dtpAtual.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, você tem que usar o evento dos dois campos pra calcular a diferença de datas...
Esse projeto é Web?

Comment: Não é... É Windows Form, plataforma para Windows.

Comment: Entendi... se fosse web eu ia te falar pra usar javascript.... Coloca sua resposta no campo de resposta pra plataforma identificar que sua pergunta foi respondida...

Comment: @JoaoTorresMoreira, se a questão foi resolvida, você pode postar a resposta e marca-lá como tal. Não precisa alterar o título da pergunta

Comment: @RovannLinhalis obrigado pela sugestão! Ja coloquei resposta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESPOSTA:

Inclui o codigo para evento dptAtual_ValueChanged:

```
Private Sub dtpAtual_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles dtpAtual.ValueChanged Dim dtEscolha As DateTime dtEscolha = dtpAtual.Text txtBoxDe.Text = dtEscolha.AddYears(-5) End Sub
```